# Iterate through an array of hashes and save each hash as a record in a ruby on rails (postgresql) table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have successfully extracted 90 articles (their titles, links and text), now want to put this data into a table

I created the table:

```
rails g model Article title:string link:string paragraphs:text
```

In the irb, I can run my extraction (using Nokogiri) to get the data and set it equal to articlesArray

But I cannot figure out what to do next. I cannot work out the correct syntax to get the data successfully into the table

I am still in the irb (not in rails c) - if that makes any difference

I am really struggling

**Here are a few things I've tried so far**

```
for i in 0...articlesArray.length
    Article.create(
        title: articlesArray[i].title,
        link: articlesArray[i].link,
        paragraphs: articlesArray[i].paragraphs.text[176...articlesArray[i].paragraphs.text.length-283]      
        )
end
```

Trying another approach

```
for i in 0...articlesArray.length-1

@article = Article.new

@article.title = articlesArray[i].title
@article.link = articlesArray[i].link
@article.paragraphs = articlesArray[i].paragraphs.text[176...articlesArray[i].paragraphs.text.length-283] 

@article.save
end
```

And again

```
articlesArray.each do |article|

    @article = Article.new

    @article.title = article.title
    @article.link = article.link
    @article.paragraphs = article.paragraphs.text[176...article.paragraphs.text.length-283] 

    @article.save
end
```

None of these seem to work

Comment: Why do you think it does not work? Any errors or?

Comment: Try to debug it first, for example: 
`1: article_data = articlesArray.first
  2: article = Article.new(title: article_data.title, link: article_data.link, paragraphs: article_data.paragraphs.text[176...article.paragraphs.text.length-283])
  3: article.save
  4: puts article.errors`

Comment: @AlexGolubenko running what you suggest gives: SyntaxError ((irb):142: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
...raphs.text.length-283]) article.save puts article.errors

Comment: I updated my comment, do it by steps.

Comment: The first step works. The second step says: NoMethodError (undefined method `paragraphs' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: ok, after 1 step, do `puts article_data`

Comment: If I type the word article_data it returns all the data for the first article. But when I try puts article_data it gives: #<Article:0x00007f950f9f7170>
=> nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169090/discussion-between-alex-golubenko-and-user5783745).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
articlesArray.each do |article|
    Article.create(
        title: article.title,
        link: article.link,
        paragraphs: article.paragraphs
        )
end
```